# Failed to update system apps

Tags: apps, windows-10-mobile, store

I am using Nokia Lumia 720 with Windows 10. Windows store shows few apps(Equaliser, Rate your device, Gestures & Touch) to be updated. But, when I click to update them it fails saying "Error - see details"

Comment: And what does the details say?

Comment: Nothing. When I click on detail it starts downloading again and fails

Comment: remove all those downloads, restart your device and again recheck for updates.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. I fixed it by doing the following steps.

1. Cancel any pending downloads.
2. Go to *Settings-> System-> Apps* and uninstall those apps.
3. Restart your phone.
4. Open the store.
5. Reinstall those apps(You can find those apps in MyLibrary).